# How to use a variable AS a where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one where clause which I have to use multiple times. I am quite new to Oracle SQL, so please forgive me for my newbe mistakes :). I have read this website, but could not find the answer :(. Here's the SQL statement:

```
    var condition varchar2(100)
    exec :condition := 'column 1 = 1 AND column2 = 2, etc.'

    Select a.content, b.content 
    from
    (Select (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3)) as content
    from table_name
    where category = X AND :condition
    group by (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3))
    ) A
    ,
    (Select (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,100)) as content
    from table_name
    where category = Y AND :condition
    group by (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,100))) B
    GROUP BY
    a.content, b.content
```

The content field is a CLOB field and unfortunately all values needed are in the same column. My query does not work ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a bind variable for that much of a `where` clause, only for specific values. You could use a substitution variable if you're running this in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (and maybe some other clients):

```
define condition = 'column 1 = 1 AND column2 = 2, etc.'

Select a.content, b.content 
from
(Select (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3)) as content
from table_name
where category = X AND &condition
...
```

From other places, including JDBC and OCI, you'd need to have the condition as a variable and build the query string using that, so it's repeated in the code that the parser sees. From PL/SQL you could use dynamic SQL to achieve the same thing. I'm not sure why just repeating the conditions is a problem though, binding arguments if values are going to change. Certainly with two clauses like this it seems a bit pointless.

But maybe you could approach this from a different angle and remove the need to repeat the `where` clause. Querying the table twice might not be efficient anyway. You could apply your condition once as a subquery, but without knowing your indexes or the selectivity of the conditions this could be worse:

```
with sub_table as (
  select category, content
  from my_table
  where category in (X, Y)
  and column 1 = 1 AND column2 = 2, etc.
)
Select a.content, b.content 
from
(Select (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3)) as content
from sub_table
where category = X
group by (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3))
) A
,
(Select (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,100)) as content
from sub_table
where category = Y
group by (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,100))) B
GROUP BY
a.content, b.content
```

I'm not sure what the grouping is for - to eliminate duplicates? This only really makes sense if you have a single X and Y record matching the other conditions, doesn't it? Maybe I'm not following it properly.

You could also use a `case` statement:

```
select max(content_x), max(content_y)
from (
  select
    case when category = X
      then DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,3) end as content_x,
    case when category = Y
      then DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ost_bama_vrij_veld.inhoud,100) end as content_y,
    from my_table
    where category in (X, Y)
    and column 1 = 1 AND column2 = 2, etc.
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the first query works perfectly in SQL developer. I have to check if it works for BI publisher too :). 
The second query is a good idea. I haven't used the with statement before, but I will definitely try it out (to see which one performs better). 
The group by is needed becuase the application which runs the query also sends a from  and where clause, creating the duplicates. These clauses are given by the end user.